# How to match three letter month name in Hive queries

Tags: hive, hiveql

How can we match a date value like **2014-Dec-20** in unix_timestamp()? The pattern **yyyy-MM-dd** matches 2014-12-20 format. But yyyy-mmm-dd or yyyy-m-dd doesn't do the trick for matching the month name.

Answer (score 3):

Got the answer from the hive community. "MMM" will match the three letter month code in unix_timestamp() in Hive.
eg: select request,unix_timestamp(time,'dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss') from apachelogs;